# Redirecting from a JSP to a controller Spring

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have a JSP that I want to use to call a controller (that's linked to another JSP page) when a URL is clicked, my code is as follows:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Spring MVC Hello World Example</h1>

    <h2>${msg}</h2>

     <a href="/FileMonitor/ResultPage/">click</a>

</body>
</html>
```

The class I want to call at `/FileMonitor/ResultPage/` is here:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/Result")
public class ResultController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("ResultPage");
        model.addObject("msg", "result");

        return model;
    }

}
```

But I'm getting a 404, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? How can I access the controller from the JSP page?

Comment: Could you tell us the visible adress wich gives you a 404 ? I guess it's something like localhost:8080/FileMonitor/ResultPage/. If so, follow @liya solution

Answer (score 2):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/FileMonitor/ResultPage/")
public class ResultController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("ResultPage");
        model.addObject("msg", "result");

        return model;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [url tag from JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Spring MVC Hello World Example</h1>

    <h2>${msg}</h2>

    <a href="<c:url value="/FileMonitor/ResultPage/"/>">click</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi there, I've tried using this example but I still get a 404, any ideas why?

Comment: Could it be a problem with my web.xml?

Comment: Do you have @RequestMapping(value="/FileMonitor/ResultPage/") before your controller class?

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that `<a href="/something />` link will redirect you to the server root (because of the "/"). To prevent that, you have two options :

- setting the absolute path :

> "/myProject/something"

- using the JSTL tag `<c:url value="/something"/>` wich will add the `"/myProject"` on the url.